# configure error line 38: sort: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, paths, configure

Using `configure`, ends with the following message:

```
./configure: line 38: sort: No such file or directory
./configure: line 35: sed: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a path with a newline in `$PATH`. Removing it resolved the error.

More information: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRBNmayqexB9pqv0NCjaxY-4i3xeQFJoAOcUwott9JA5qg%40mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I had received the same error when installing https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/

Even after checking the PATH variable, I couldn't see any problem in it.

Finally, I made the following change in configure file after which it gave no such error.

```
s@ sed@ /path/to/sed@g
s@ sort@ /path/to/sort@g
```